# How to XOR two chars as decimals in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, unix, char, xor

I need to perform XOR of two characters. I got this function, but it wont print what I would expect:

```
#!/bin/sh

xor() {
    key=$1
    length=${#key}
    while read -r -N1 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        echo $((byte ^ char))
    done
}

echo "5555" | xor "4567"
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
4
```

I would expect for input 5555 with mask 4567 to see output:

```
1
0
3
2
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
So I changed my function to this:

```
xor() {
    key=$1
    length=${#key}
    i=0
    while read -r -N1 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        echo $((byte ^ char))
    done
}
```

Still getting error, when try to call:

```
cat $2 | xor $1
```

// $1 is key and $2 is filename

As a file I use standart text file and as a key a string.
It says there is error on line `echo $((byte ^ char))` <: syntactic mistake: expecting operand (wrong token is "<")

Comment: What's `i`? You never set a value for it.

Comment: I believe there is no need to initialize `i` value, it will be `0` by default. EDIT: It is working without `i=0`

Answer (score 5):

You are not moving to next character in `key`. Add `((i++))` at the end the loop:

```
xor() {
    key=$1
    length=${#key}
    while read -r -N1 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        echo $((byte ^ char))
    done
}

echo -n "5555" | xor "4567"
```

`echo` would send a newline character which you probably don't want. So skip it with `-n`. Passing two arguments would be more cleaner in my opinion.

I would also suggest not use `/bin/sh` as a shebang since the script is actually `bash`. `/bin/sh` might be linked to different shell on different systems. It's not always safe. Always use the proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Both are mistakes I did not noticed. Thank you.